# Best collaboration and file sharing platform across multiple organizations (and IT ecosystems)

Tags: file-system, file-access, microsoft-sharepoint-online

Four discrete organizations wish to share calendars, files, and folders for collaboration purposes on multi-year projects (including regular online and in-person events).

Each one has their own separate environment (MS 365 and proprietary), with strict data sharing protocols (outside users cannot simply be added and there is scrutiny at every step, with each file-sharing event, calendar check, edit requiring a login and often, 2-step verification).

Does anyone have any recommendations for the best way to share and collaborate on files and data, given these? (Non MS 365 ideas welcome? Our SharePoints do not play well with each other and we have limited influence over IT teams' policies.)

The key points again are:

- file sharing
- calendar sharing and editability
- track collaborations and edits
- minimize authentications and 2-step verifications as edits and sharing are done rapidly and in a high-iteration environment

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: This isn't security related.

Comment: This is a SharePoint/365 issue.